# When I add a column, I can't retrieve it from mysql

Tags: php

After I add a column to my database, I want to retrieve it but not expected.
In PHP, I try reopening apache and mysql still not work.

Does anyone know how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: Please post more information - error logs, php code etc

Comment: Please re-read your question and try to get into the mindset of someone that has no idea about your specific problem. How could that guy solve the problem with that amount of informations now? Could you understand what is going on?

Comment: I am able to do it. Not sure why you can't.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not fully explanatory but with what I could try to understand you want to retrieve data or records from your database
you could try the code below and tweak it to work your way

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM databaseName";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data 
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            print $row"<br>";
       }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
   }
   $conn->close();
?>
```